# Spring Boot application fails to start because of 'ThymeleafViewResolver' bean creation exception

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring boot application fails to start because of 'thymeleafViewResolver' bean creation Exception.

Springboot version: 2.7.10
Build: Maven

We use spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf maven dependency for 'Thymeleaf'

When we try to deploy the Spring bot application in container we get following exception sometimes:

```json
{
  "localizedMessage": "Error creating bean with name ‘thymeleafViewResolver’ defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method ‘thymeleafViewResolver’ parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘templateEngine’ defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/TemplateEngineConfigurations$DefaultTemplateEngineConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory method ‘templateEngine’ threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception during initialization of Spring versioning utilities. Identified Spring version is ‘eb516fae31635c3f1ba6178117711f1490f2df55’, which does not follow the {major}.{minor}.{patch}[.{...}] scheme",
  "message": "Error creating bean with name ‘thymeleafViewResolver’ defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method ‘thymeleafViewResolver’ parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘templateEngine’ defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/TemplateEngineConfigurations$DefaultTemplateEngineConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory method ‘templateEngine’ threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception during initialization of Spring versioning utilities. **Identified Spring version is ‘eb516fae31635c3f1ba6178117711f1490f2df55’, which does not follow the {major}.{minor}.{patch}[.{...}] **scheme",
  "name": "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException",
  "stackTrace": [
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver",
      "method": "createArgumentArray",
      "file": "ConstructorResolver.java",
      "line": 800
    },
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver",
      "method": "instantiateUsingFactoryMethod",
      "file": "ConstructorResolver.java",
      "line": 541
    },
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory",
      "method": "instantiateUsingFactoryMethod",
      "file": "AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java",
      "line": 1352
    },
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory",
      "method": "createBeanInstance",
      "file": "AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java",
      "line": 1195
    },
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory",
      "method": "doCreateBean",
      "file": "AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java",
      "line": 582
    },
    {
      "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory",
      "method": "createBean",
      "file": "AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java",
      "line": 542
    }
  ]
}
```

Weird thing is that it is not happening always.
The same docker image once working will fail next time.
This issue is not happening in local machine.

This started after Spring boot upgrade from 2.2.9.RELEASE to 2.6.10 and higher.

We could not find any dependency conflicts.

We have analysed if there is any dependency conflicts for thymeleaf and we could not find one.
The version of thymeleaf is 3.0.15.RELEASE from springboot-starter-thymeleaf.

pom.xml is :

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.10</spring.boot.version>

        <!--Spring Google Cloud dependencies-->
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.4.5</spring-cloud-gcp.version>

        <prometheus.version>0.16.0</prometheus.version>
        
        <google.gson.version>2.10</google.gson.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.7</commons-validator.version>
        <apache.httpclient.version>4.5.13</apache.httpclient.version>
        <mashape.unirest.version>1.4.9</mashape.unirest.version>
        <mvn.tattletale.version>1.1.2.Final</mvn.tattletale.version>
        <junit-jupiter-api.version>5.9.0</junit-jupiter-api.version>
        <junit-platform-commons.version>1.9.0</junit-platform-commons.version>
        <jackson.data.format.yaml.version>2.14.0</jackson.data.format.yaml.version>
        <docker.image.name>docker.io/fintechinnovation/uapi</docker.image.name>
        <lombok.verion>1.18.24</lombok.verion>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <tomitribe-http-signatures>1.8</tomitribe-http-signatures>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <tomcat-embed-el.version>10.1.0</tomcat-embed-el.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Thymeleaf dependency for html model template resolver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tomitribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomitribe-http-signatures</artifactId>
            <version>${tomitribe-http-signatures}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Embedded version have 26 vulnerabilities-->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed-el.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Monitoring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.latencyutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>LatencyUtils</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${google.gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.data.format.yaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>feature-flag-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>feature-flag-client</artifactId>
            <version>${feature-flag-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${junit-platform-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito extension -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.verion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--for Hibernate validator-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId> 
        </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-spanner</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                src/main/resources/static/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>

                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Unit tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.tattletale</groupId>
                <artifactId>tattletale-maven</artifactId>
                <!-- The version of the plugin you want to use -->
                <version>${mvn.tattletale.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- This is the location which will be scanned for generating tattletale
                        reports -->
                    <source>${project.build.directory}</source>
                    <!-- This is where the reports will be generated -->
                    <destination>${project.build.directory}/tattletale</destination>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>50%</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>50%</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```
````

Comment: `nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception during initialization of Spring versioning utilities. Identified Spring version is ‘eb516fae31635c3f1ba6178117711f1490f2df55’, which does not follow the {major}.{minor}.{patch}[.{...}] scheme` is at the end of your exception. Could you share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @JettoMartínez updated with pom.xml